# can we play audio on background

Tags: iphone

till know, i was aware of the fact is, we cant play background process in iPhone, but with 4.0 + we can do it.
i have a doubt, suppose we develop and music player application, which need to be play audio continiously, while the application has been closed.
Is this possible.
For example, the inbuilt music player of iPhone does this, if u play an audio, and close the app, it will continue playing the audio, untill you fully close the music player.
SO my doubht is, can we play music in background, while application is closed.???

Suggestions are always appreciated
regards

Answer (score 4):

Open your plist file as a plain text file and add background modes as audio.

```
<dict>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
// other codes
</dict>
```

All the Best.